# expect: spawn id exp6 not open

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am very new to scripting and trying to create a script that will automatically log into a remote server without the user having to type a username and password as the script is doing a proxy jump with a preset user_name, server and password.

The issue is when there is a successful login and when the user types exit, this error message is displayed on the console:

```
username@remote_server ~ $ exit
logout
Connection to remote_server closed.
expect: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"expect eof "
```

The other issue is that when the server is unreachable, I am not sure how to exit the script correctly. I have made a comment in the below script to what I tried.

Below is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #log into remote server
 clear 

 echo "Enter server name [ENTER]:" #prompt user for input
 read INPUT

 SERVER=`echo $INPUT`

 clear

 echo ""
 echo "Logging into $SERVER, please wait ............"
 echo ""
 export SERVER #export global variable to expect script

 #Take the gobal env variable from bash script above i.e. $SERVER and pass 
 it into the expect script below

 /usr/bin/expect -c '
 set password "password"

            expect ":~$"
            set timeout 10
            log_user 0
            spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $env(SERVER)
            expect "user_name@proxy_jump_server*:" #preset proxy jump server username and servername. User should not see this
            send "$password\r"
            expect {
                   timeout {send_user "server is unreachable"; exit} 
                   eof { ; exit } # this is where I am not sure how to exit the code correctly if the server is unreachable
                   "* ~ $"
            }
            send "clear\r"
            log_user 1
            interact
 expect eof '
```

Comment: okay I have managed to fix my 2nd issue by adding exit before expect eof '

Comment: @pynexj thank you. However I need to have this without users having to download from Git

Comment: don't `expect eof` after `interact`.

Comment: @pynexj removing expect eof after interact still does not change anything unfortunately. When a server is unreachable the script still does not exit and echos "server is unreachable".

Comment: a bit confused -- *"The other issue is that when the server is unreachable, I am not sure how to exit the script correctly."* and then in comment you said *"okay I have managed to fix my 2nd issue by adding exit before expect eof"*

Comment: @pynexj yeah sorry don't worry about the 2nd issue. The only issue I am facing at the moment is when a server is unreachable, how do I echo "failed" and scripts exit?

Comment: still confused. ur 2nd issue is *"when the server is unreachable, I am not sure how to exit the script correctly"* and u have fixed it but u r still asking the issue of *"when a server is unreachable"*. could you please update ur question to make it clear?

Comment: Did anyone get proper reasonable solution to: expect: spawn id exp6 not open  while executing
"expect eof"
???